# How to create a sub_tasks within a todo in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm very new to Dart/Flutter programming and I am trying to create a todo list with sub-tasks( a task can have any number of sub_tasks). I have tried creating a list of sub-tasks(class) within a task class. But it's not working. How can I add (multiple) sub_tasks to each task? How can I call these sub_tasks? Is there a better way to do this?

```
    class Task {

      String _mainTask;
      List<SubTask> subtasks = List<SubTask>();
      bool Expanded = false;

      Task(this._mainTask);

      getName() => this._mainTask;
      setName(name) => this._mainTask = name;

      isExpanded() => this.Expanded;
      setExpanded(expanded) => this.Expanded = expanded;


      }

      class SubTask{
      String subTask;
      bool _completed = false;

      SubTask(this.subTask);

      getsubTask() => this.subTask;
      setsubTask(subtask) => this.subTask = subtask;


      isCompleted() => this._completed;
      setCompleted(completed) => this._completed = completed;

      }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you can add items to a List with `List.add(item)`. accessing the fields of your objects with `.`. 
----> `Task task = Task(); task.subtasks.add(SubTask());`

Comment: i have tried that but I can't seem to call the string variable in SubTask class. I get the error: "type 'List<SubTask>' is not a subtype of type 'String'." I can't seem to call the variables inside the class SubTask. I know I'm probably missing something very basic here. But any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you share the lines of code where you get the error?

Comment: When I try to invoke the method: (In class Task) ------------>getSubTask() => this.subtasks; ......  (In main code)  ----> body: ListTile(
              title: Text(item.getSubTask()),
              subtitle: Text('delete'),
              trailing: Icon(Icons.delete),
              onTap: () ....... Basically, how can I invoke the variables(through the getter and setter) in SubTask class? I can create a SubTask class by using the  task.subtasks.add(SubTask()); but how can I access the  getsubTask and 'isCompleted'  methods in the SubTask class from outside this class?